# Get a folder in my checklist box vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub GetContainerButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetContainerButton.Click

    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\folder test")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
    For Each dra In diar1
        Container.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub
```

In my folder test, there is a folder named ABC, 123.txt, 234.txt.
Hi this is my code for getting the folder in folder test, but i can only get the text file (123.txt, 234.txt) in the folder. I want to get the folder (ABC)in my folder test as

Comment: If you call a method named `GetFiles` then why would you be surprised that what it does is get files?  If you want folders or files and folders then it would stand to reason that you'd need to call a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each folder As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\folder test")
         Container.Items.Add(folder)
Next
```

This gets directory names instead of file names.

Comment: Dude, are you serious?